# Why does the double integral for the area of a circle of radius$1$ equal $\pi/8 $ instead of $\pi/4$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, trigonometry, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates

Like [double integral a for quarter circle area](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=double%20integral%20of%200%20to%20pi%2F2%20and%200%20to%201%20of%20(1%20-%20r%5E2)*r%20dr%20dtheta):
$$
    \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^1 (1-r^2) r\,dr\,d\theta = \frac{\pi}{8}
$$

If that truly is the representation of a quarter circle of radius 1 in polar coordinates, it must equal $\pi/4$. So, why is this *not* a quarter circle of radius one and is instead equal to $\pi/8$ suggesting a circle of radius $\sqrt2 / 2$ ?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you integrating $(1 - r^2)\cdot r$? Would be nice if you'd put the integral into the question, and the way you arrived to it.

Comment: The mathematician-and-plumber joke is almost relevant here: http://jokes.nick-santos.com/2007/05/mathematician-and-plumber.html

Answer (score 3):

It's just not true that this integral is "the representation of a quarter circle of radius 1 in polar coordinates."  The *domain* over which you are integrating is a quarter disk, but you're integrating a function $f(r,\theta) = 1-r^2$ over that domain.

There is a danger in calculus (especially in the transition from single to multivariable) to think of integrals as area.  In fact, integrals can be used to accumulate any function.  For instance, you can think of the function as measuring charge density over a metal plate in the shape of the domain.  Then the integral measures total charge.

If you want an integral over a plane region that computes the area of the region, use $f(r,\theta)=1$.  Then
$$
    \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^1 r\,dr\,d\theta = \left[\frac{r^2}{2}\right]^1_0 
    \left[\theta\right]^{\pi/2}_0 = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{\pi}{2} = \frac{\pi}{4}
$$
However, this doesn't prove the area formula.  The polar coordinates integration formula is derived from the area formula for this disk.  So this is—wait for it—circular logic.

Comment: Nice answer. However, I don't quite agree with the last sentence: the integral depends only on the change of variable cartesian-polar (to get the $rdrd\theta$), and this simply comes from a jacobian determinant. Then you only need to know that a circle is made of the points at distance $r$ from the center. Where is the area of the circle?

Comment: I don't think the logic is circular... You don't need to know the area of a circle to tell that the infinitesimal area element is $r\,drd\theta$. It's just basic similarity, possibly along with the circumference. In fact, I would personally deduce the area as $\int_0^1(2\pi r)dr$, which can also be interpreted as $\int_0^1\int_0^{2\pi}r\,d\theta dr$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut and Arthur—you could be right.  I was thinking of the derivation of the polar coordinates formula that uses the fact that the area of a polar rectangle is $\bar r \,\Delta r \,\Delta \theta$.  I believe that formula relies on the fact that the area of a rectangle is $\pi r^2$.  In any case, I hope you'll forgive my glibness in my haste to make a pun.